# How to access \@title from a custom class

Tags: titles, documentclass-writing

I was trying to write a custom LaTeX class where I need to access the value of `\@title`. I wrote

```
\newcommand{\makeack}{Hello World  \@title World}
```

But the value of `\@title` is not printed when I use `\makeack` in the `.tex` file. But I could successfully use `\@title` in the modified `\@maketitle` I defined like

```
\def\@maketitle{% 
....
....
}
```

I am a beginner in writing classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default document classes make the title-related macros (`\@title`, `\@date` and `\@author`) empty once you call `\maketitle`. If you wish to keep copies of them around, you need to store these elsewhere. One way would be to update the `\title` (and friends) macro to not only store its contents in `\@title` (yes, that's what `\title` does), but also in something for *your* use, like `\stored@title`, say:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\stored@title{#1}}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}\gdef\stored@author{#1}}
\def\date#1{\gdef\@date{#1}\gdef\stored@date{#1}}
```

The [`titling` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) does a similar thing, if you're interested.